# how to make task to run between specific time interval with n number of times every 5minutes in a dag

Tags: airflow

Is there any possibility we can create a dag and inside that task should run multiple iterations in every 10 minutes between a time frame..

We have two tasks : t1 and t2

t1 should run for 20 times in a day for every 5 minutes of gap and once 20 times is completed it should trigger a task2 (t2)

tried creating two different dags it worked but do we have any way to do it in a single dag.

Any suggestions please ..

```
task_1(run for 20 times each time should have 5 minutes of gap and then) >> task_2
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you try something like this: (this is not executable code)

```
for i in range(1,6):
    task1 = SomeOperator(id = f"task1_execution{i}")
    sleep = BashOperator(id=f'sleep_{i}', command='sleep 5')
task2 = SomeOperator(id = "task2_execution")

task1 >> task2
```